# Aprovação de fonte usando SVN

Tags: svn, versionamento, tortoisesvn

Existe alguma maneira de controlar a aprovação de um arquivo do respositório SVN?
Caso não exista uma aprovação explícita, existe alguma outra maneira similar (como nos projetos openSource) de controlar a entrada de arquivos no repositório?

Obrigado!

Comment: Está muito vago, explique melhor ou dê um exemplo do que você quer dizer com "controlar a aprovação/entrada de arquivos". Você está falando de algo como o .gitignore? ou então pre-commit hooks? ou talvez esteja confundindo git com github e se referindo a pull requests?

Comment: Seguinte @BrunoRB. Neste repositório eu tenho vários desenvolvedores trabalhando. Para alguns, eu gostaria de exigir uma aprovação para evitar que fossem feitos "commits" sem uma avaliação mais apurada do que está sendo feito. 

Seria um pré-commit como você mencionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você fazer exatamente o que quer, receber o commit no servidor e manter ele fora do repositório até o momento que der uma aprovação, eu acredito que seria razoávelmente complicado, você precisa construir toda a interface para isto já que até onde eu lembro não tem nada pronto exatamente neste modelo.

Como alternativa eu te sugiro duas opções:

1. Você aceita os commits normalmente, contudo faz um [post-commit hook](http://svnbook-pt-br.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/1.4/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) que te alerta (email, telegram, etc) que houve uma alteração no código feita pelo usuário X (você faz o script com condições para que só dispare para certos users) no arquivo Y revisão W, assim você pode rever se o código da tal pessoa não precisa ser revertido.
2. Você cria um [branch](http://svnbook-pt-br.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/1.4/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html) do repositório e exige com que os devs façam os commits apenas nele e só permite que eles façam merge das alteração no trunk (branch principal) após o código ter sido revisto.

Também seria possível combinar as duas estratégias e fazer com que commits no branch gerem alertas, agilizando o processo de revisão para dar o "ok, pode fazer o merge no trunk".

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, acho que a ideia de usar um branch intermediário seja a melhor. Vi que o SVN possibilita a criação de scripts pré-commit, o que daria pra fazer uma ferramenta pra controlar essas aprovações.
Mas acho que a sua segunda alternativa seja a mais viável no momento.

Obrigado pela ajuda!